# What is the opposite of .match() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation

It may seem like an obvious answer but I read mixed answers in the net so I decided to ask here. I make a client side validation and come fields must be validate that their value is a float number. I made my check like this :

```
else if ($(".checkFloat").val().match('^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$'))
```

But what I actually need is the opposite of that. If the value doesn't match this pattern then... In all languages that I've been using the `!` is used for such kind of things but I'm not sure where exactly is the place for it and if it's actually working (I couldn't find examples using `!`).

So.. how to to my check properly?

Comment: you know that if `.checkfloat` collection has length > 1 then your use of `val()` will cause `match` to only be performed against the first item in the collection?  if so then you're okay.  if not then you'll have to use a different selector or iterate over the collection checking `match` for each item (e.g. `$(this).val().match()`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
else if (!$(".checkFloat").val().match('^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$'));
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use  `!$(".checkFloat").val().match('^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$')`

use `!` for not  condition

Answer (score 3):

Just use `!` before the value that returned from your expression like this. So it will negate the returned value.

```
else if (!$(".checkFloat").val().match('^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is very simple

```
else if (!$(".checkFloat").val().match('^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$'))
```